# Appending url to the body of mailto

Tags: javascript

How to append location.href url in mailto body.

```
  appendToUrl3 =window.location.href;
 <a href="mailto:googlehelp_r@gmail.com?Subject=Help%20Google-%20Results&body="+appendToUrl3 >GoogleResults</a>
```

When i do console.log(appendToUrl3); url is printing correctly
but in the mail body url is not getting appended - Its still blank body

I tried the below ones it append this in the body +appendToUrl3

```
 <a href="mailto:googlehelp_r@gmail.com?Subject=Help%20Google-%20Results&body=+appendToUrl3">GoogleResults</a>
```

Please help to append the url in the body of mailto

Comment: You can't mix HTML and JavaScript like that – to change the value of an HTML attribute with JavaScript, you can't put JavaScript inside the `href=""`. The JavaScript must be separate. JavaScript is defined in code in a `<script>` element (or a `.js` file that the element links to). In your JavaScript, use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to find your link on the page and edit its attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript for this.  It looks like you're trying to embed JavaScript inside an HTML tag, which is not valid.

JavaScript code *can* be embedded in HTML tags in the form of event handlers.  Examples include the `onload`, `onclick`, and `onmouseover` attributes.  [More on events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Listening_to_events_in_Firefox_extensions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Listening_to_events#Simple_DOM.c2.a0events).

There are *much* more maintainable ways to do this, but here is a quick and dirty solution, using the `onclick` event handler:

```
<a href="mailto:googlehelp_r@gmail.com?Subject=Help%20Google-%20Results&body=" onclick="this.href+=escape(window.location.href)">GoogleResults</a>
```